# Shorten URL with Javascript using JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, short, short-url

I am trying to short a Link over API and get the result with JSON

Some information about the API

**Sample Response**

```
{"error":0,"short":"http:\/\/doma.in\/sf0x6"}
```

**Sample Usage in PHP**

```
$content=@file_get_contents("http://doma.in/api/?url=http://www.google.com&api=APIKEY");

$url=json_decode($content,TRUE);//Decodes json into an array

if(!$url["error"]){  // If there is no error
  echo $url["short"]; //Outputs the short url
}
else{ 
  echo $url["msg"]; //Outputs the error message
}
```

**Request to Shorten a Long URL**

```
GET http://doma.in/api/?url=http://www.google.com&api=APIKEY
```

*json_short.php*

```
function curPageURL() {
 $pageURL = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
 $pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
 return $pageURL;
}

$url = curPageURL();

$json_short = @file_get_contents("http://doma.in/api/?url=$url&api=APIKEY");
echo $json_short;
```

*json_short.js*

```
$.getJSON('json_short.php', function(data) {
    if(!data.error){ // If there is no error
        alert(data.short) //Outputs the short url
    }
    else{
        alert(data.msg)
    }
});
```

Comment: CORS should be preventing you from it. You need to use a JSONP endpoint instead

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I am a beginner at coding. Could you tell me where I should use JSONP?

Comment: The URL shortener needs to support JSONP. Otherwise, you need to stick using PHP for it. Either way, it is better using PHP at server-side for it since that way your application key is not openly disclosed

Comment: You know you're missing an quote in here ["short":http://doma.in/mnQRi"] just after the colon right?

Comment: Ok you mean at the Sample Response.

Comment: But with PHP is not a Dynamic URL shortner! It just shortning the URL of where the PHP File is placed.

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript to simplify the process:

```
var foo = window.location.href;
var bar = foo.replace(/[a-z0-9.]+\//g, shortener);

function shortener(match, pos, fullstring)
  {
  if (shortener.count === foo.match(/[a-z0-9.]+\//g).length)
    {
    shortener.count = 0;
    }
  else
    {
    shortener.count = shortener.count + 1 || 0;
    }
  if (shortener.count === 1)
    {
    return "";
    }

   else
    {
    return match;
    }
  }
```