# Generate Viewing Link JS

Tags: javascript

I have a static website (HTML, CSS, JS) where people can keep track of their times.

I would like it so that they can generate a link that creates a new html page to display their time. I would like this link to be shareable, so other people can see the time.

e.g.

I time myself and get a really good time that I would like to share. I generate a link which is linked to that time, and send it to my friends, who on clicking that link can see the time & other details associated with it.

Is this possible, and if it is, how?

Thanks

Comment: Question: *Is this possible?*, Answer: *It is possible*

Comment: You need to tell us what have you tried and didn't work, or at least share some code and tell us the environment of your app, is it a PHP, NODE, NET app? More details, this is a general question and what you want to do is achievable in many ways depending on your data and environment...

Comment: Done. I don't really know where to start though so I don't have any snippets.

Comment: You can use some database to save all time and create a default page that change with url.

Comment: The site is static so I don't have a database

Comment: No you can simply url encode data

Comment: so use md5 (or another encode) to encode data and put in url.

Comment: So in conclusion, I need a server-side language to do this. Am I right?

Comment: if u just need show time, no.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more in an answer what to do? Since I'm a bit confused now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a working demo to show you what you can do w/o database and keep data unmodified and "secure".

When you press "share" it encode with [btoa](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/btoa) JS function your time and name value to url and then generate a link.

When someone go to link, it read the params from URL `?time=XXX?name=XXXX` and then decode them with [atob](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/atob) JS function then set name et timer elements text to display on page.

NOTE: Remove first  `const queryString = '?time=MTBtMjFz&name=Q29kZXJHdXJ1WFla';` and uncomment  `const queryString = '?time=MTBtMjFz&name=Q29kZXJHdXJ1WFla';` to make this code work on your page server.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  let timerEl = document.getElementById('timer');
  let nameEl = document.getElementById('name');
  const queryString = '?time=MTBtMjFz&name=U2FtIEJaRVo='; //Get the time parameter index.html?time=MTBtMjFz&name=Q29kZXJHdXJ1WFla" from URL (encoded with javascript)
  //Uncomment next line in production 
  //const queryString = window.location.search;
  if (queryString !== '') {
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
    const time = urlParams.get('time');
    const name = urlParams.get('name');
    timerEl.innerText = window.atob(time);
    nameEl.innerText = window.atob(name)
  }
  let share = document.getElementById('share');
  share.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    //Generate URL 
    document.getElementById('sharelink').innerText = 'http://example.com/timer.html?time=' + window.btoa(timerEl.innerText) + '&name=' + window.btoa(nameEl.innerText);
  });
}
```

```html
<!-- Consider this page URL is http://example.com/timer.html -->
<main>
  <h1>I'm <span id="name"></span></h1>
  <h2> My time is: <span id="timer"></span></h2>
  <button id="share">Share my time !</button>
  <h3 id="sharelink"></h3>
</main>
```

Comment: Try to understand it, dont just copy/paste ;) You're welcome.

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense after going through it and editing it. btoa and atob are really useful :)

Comment: Is there a way to shorten this link? It's a bit long :/

Comment: Yes sure, take a lookt at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14797289/shorten-url-with-javascript-using-json but you need to store file somewhere to have an index of your URLs

Comment: Another idea is to generate a QRcode to share

Answer (score 0):

if you just need show time and not worry with security you can use get parameters. You make url like: `yoursite.com/time?time=20` and in your time page:

```js
function findGetParameter(parameterName) {
    var result = null,
        tmp = [];
    location.search
        .substr(1)
        .split("&")
        .forEach(function (item) {
          tmp = item.split("=");
          if (tmp[0] === parameterName) result = decodeURIComponent(tmp[1]);
        });
    return result;
}

// Your time as stored in this variable.
var time = findGetParameter("time");
```

but i recommend a database with server-side langague like PHP, NODE or .NET.

Comment: Its returning null :/

Comment: @CoderGuruXYZ how you make test?